# Pacemaker two floating IPs

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker

I have an issue with pacemaker and two floating ips in Centos7. I have two servers with two network interfaces each one. (Public and Private). I'm trying to configure two floating ips, one public and one private, because i'll have devices connected in both. And i want switching from one to other if fail one of two interfaces.
So, with one virtual IP system works ok. With two, when an interface fail, ping stops. That's may configuration steps:

/etc/hosts in both servers:

server1 10.0.0.80

server1private 192.168.123.80

server2 10.0.0.90

server2private 192.168.123.90

Server1:

enp0s3: 
        inet 10.0.0.80  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255

enp0s8: 
        inet 192.168.123.80  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.123.255

Server2:

enp0s3:
         inet 10.0.0.80  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
enp0s8:
         inet 10.0.0.80  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255

In server1:

pcs cluster auth server1 server2

pcs cluster auth asterisk1private server2private

pcs cluster setup --name clusterHA server1,server1private 
server2,server2private

cluster start --all

pcs property set stonith-enabled=false

pcs property set no-quorum-policy=ignore

pcs resource create publicIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=10.0.0.110 cidr_netmask=32 nic=enp0s3  op monitor interval=30s

pcs resource create privateIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=192.168.123.110 cidr_netmask=32 nic=enp0s8  op monitor interval=30s

pcs constraint colocation add publicIP privateIP INFINIY

pcs status is ok.
corosync-cfgtool -s is ok. (Two rings)

pcs status:

Cluster name: clusterHA
Last updated: Thu Dec  1 00:29:13 2016      Last change: Thu Dec  1 00:29:01 2016 by root via cibadmin on asterisk1
Stack: corosync
Current DC: server1 (version 1.1.13-10.el7_2.4-44eb2dd) - partition with quorum
2 nodes and 2 resources configured

Online: [ server1 server2 ]

Full list of resources:

publicIP   (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started server2
 privateIP  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started server2
PCSD Status:
  server1: Online
  server2: Online

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled

Now, i can ping 10.0.0.110 and 192.168.123.110
But, if i shut down in server 2 interface enp0s8, ping to 192.168.123.110 stop, and i go this message:

pcs status every ok, like before, and
corosync-cfgtool -s

local node ID 1
RING ID 0

```
id  = 10.0.0.80

status  = ring 0 active with no faults
```

RING ID 1

```
id  = 192.168.123.80

status  = Marking ringid 1 interface 192.168.123.80 FAULTY
```

What am i doing wrong? is this way ok? or maybe is there other to way to do that?
Thanks in advance to everybody!

Comment: I think this question would be better suited for www.serverfault.com

Comment: OK, i've already moved. Thanks